# What is a better way to create a game loop on the iPhone other than using NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am programming a game on the iPhone.  I am currently using NSTimer to trigger my game update/render.  The problem with this is that (after profiling) I appear to lose a lot of time between updates/renders and this seems to be mostly to do with the time interval that I plug into NSTimer.

So my question is what is the best alternative to using NSTimer?

One alternative per answer please.

Comment: Have you looked at the iPhone developer examples? I think there are some examples (Touch Fighter or CrashLanding, for example) that might be illuminating.

Comment: I have looked at many examples and researched alternatives on the internet.  So I already know there some alternatives.  What I am really after is what other people think the best alternative is?  I am working on an extremely short project so any time saved on investigation will be a big help.

Answer (score 18):

You can get a better performance with threads, try something like this:

```
- (void) gameLoop
{
    while (running)
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        [self renderFrame];
        [pool release];
    }
}

- (void) startLoop
{
    running = YES;
#ifdef THREADED_ANIMATION
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(gameLoop)
    toTarget:self withObject:nil];
#else
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f/60
    target:self selector:@selector(renderFrame) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
#endif
}

- (void) stopLoop
{
    [timer invalidate];
    running = NO;
}
```

In the `renderFrame` method You prepare the framebuffer, draw frame and present the framebuffer on screen. (P.S. There is a great [article](http://dewitters.koonsolo.com/gameloop.html) on various types of game loops and their pros and cons.)

Comment: -1. UIView is not thread-safe, so you need to do a whole bunch of other stuff to make it work. UIGraphics is only thread-safe since 4.0.

Comment: @tc: You’re right, but the poster doesn’t say anything about the graphics layer he uses. Since we are talking about games, I assumed OpenGL, where such a loop works without problems.

Comment: @zoul: does the `THREADED_ANIMATION` alternative also work for earlier versions? I thought I read it didn't somewhere.

Comment: You mean earlier iOS versions? Yes, I haved used similar code in games around 2.x or 3.x.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the iPhone in particular, but I may still be able to help:
Instead of simply plugging in a fixed delay at the end of the loop, use the following:

- Determine a refresh interval that you would be happy with and that is larger than a single pass through your main loop.
- At the start of the loop, take a current timestamp of whatever resolution you have available and store it.
- At the end of the loop, take another timestamp, and determine the elapsed time since the last timestamp (initialize this before the loop).
- sleep/delay for the difference between your ideal frame time and the already elapsed time this for the frame.
- At the next frame, you can even try to compensate for inaccuracies in the sleep interval by comparing to the timestamp at the start of the previous loop. Store the difference and add/subtract it from the sleep interval at the end of this loop (sleep/delay can go too long OR too short).

You might want to have an alert mechanism that lets you know if you're timing is too tight(i,e, if your sleep time after all the compensating is less than 0, which would mean you're taking more time to process than your frame rate allows). The effect will be that your game slows down. For extra points, you may want to simplify rendering for a while, if you detect this happening, until you have enough spare capacity again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CADisplayLink, you can find how in the OpenGL ES template project provided in XCODE (create a project starting from this template and give a look to the EAGLView class, this example is based on open GL, but you can use CADisplayLink only for other kind of games