# Why do Cocoa games avoid Grand Central Dispatch for creating a timer?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I'm looked a far deal around the internet discussing creating game loops in Cocoa. Most of the game loops I've seen use NSTimer to trigger an event every 60th of a second. Why does there appear to be no examples that use Grand Central Dispatch, like in the source code from Apple's Developers Documentation below. Is there a problem that I don't know about?

```
dispatch_source_t CreateDispatchTimer(uint64_t interval,
              uint64_t leeway,
              dispatch_queue_t queue,
              dispatch_block_t block)
{
   dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER,
                                                     0, 0, queue);
   if (timer)
   {
      dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), interval, leeway);
      dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block);
      dispatch_resume(timer);
   }
   return timer;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because NSTimer is more famous, less frightening than GCD and because GCD is only MacOS10.6.x/iOS4.x and above only?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the reply. It's probably is because it isn't backward compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I think the answer is. I wish nacho4d would have posted it as an answer so I could green it, but I'm using this opportunity to get the self-learner Skinner Box reward.

> Maybe because NSTimer is more famous,
>   less frightening than GCD and because
>   GCD is only MacOS10.6.x/iOS4.x and
>   above only? – nacho4d Feb 13 at 8:01

Answer (score 12):

This does not really answer your question, but a regular timer is not the perfect game loop solution (though it might be the easiest one). There is [a very good article about game loop programming](http://dewitters.koonsolo.com/gameloop.html) and two [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96265) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834730) about game loops on SO that might give you better ideas.

The main point is running the game loop on a separate thread in a loop and recalculate the game model according to the time elapsed between the iterations:

```
- (void) gameLoop
{
    while (running) {
        CFAbsoluteTime now = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        CFTimeInterval deltaTime = now - lastTime;
        [self updateModelWithDelta:deltaTime];
        [self renderFrame];
        lastTime = now;
    }
}
```

This will give you maximum smoothness. Read the linked sources for more information, writing a nice threaded game loop is not hard and makes a big difference, IMHO.