# NSTimer on device is slower than in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I am new to iPhone development. I used `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01]` for game loop. The game consists drawscreen function in which I use `CGContextClipToRect` to clip the large images for animation.

But the speed 0.01 seconds is working in simulator only not on device. How can I overcome this problem?

The timer code is in view controller as

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    GameView *main = [[GameView alloc] 
    initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]]; 
    main.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    self.view = main; 
    [main release];    
    self.tim = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.01         
    target: self selector: @selector (gameloop:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES]; 
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: 100 updates per second is probably a bit optimistic.

Comment: For one thing, what U62 said; try 1.0/30.0 instead. Moreover: Be more specific. You say it's “not working” on the device, but what do you mean by “not working”?

Answer (score 1):

NSTimer is the wrong tool for this job. It's not meant to be a real-time timer. It has no guarantees on when it will fire, and you can miss frames easily.

There are a lot of good recommendations for how to develop this kind of program on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96265/what-is-a-better-way-to-create-a-game-loop-on-the-iphone-other-than-using-nstimer). Note particularly the references to Apple's sample code.

Answer (score 0):

As U62 said, 100fps is not a realistic expectation, try running it at 30, maybe 60 updates a second and see how it runs. Also if your writing a game that need to run at a high frame rate you should look into writing it in OpenGL.

One option may be to process logic every tick, but only draw to the screen every few ticks.

Answer (score 0):

i mean ,for example when i animate frames ,frames are shown in correct speed in simulator.
but in device it shows very slow(FPS)in other words a boy runs fastly in simulator.but in 
device he walks.