# Take 20 screenshots a second Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to take 20 screenshots a second for 3 seconds, all those added to a `UIImage` array that gets converted into a video.

Here is the code im using to take a screenshot:

```
func screenshot() {
        var imageSize = CGSize.zero

        let orientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
        if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) {
            imageSize = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size
        } else {
            imageSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height, height: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.width)
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 0)
        for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
            window.drawHierarchy(in: window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        images.append(image!)

    }
```

I've read the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982374/how-to-take-30-screenshots-in-a-second-in-an-ios-device), though it is quiet old and i'm sure that at 20FPS for 3 seconds it can be done, but i am not sure of which would be the best way to achieve it.

**Edit:** *Use UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size rather than UIScreen.main.bounds.size or you will get the 'wrong' image size , and it can be quiet a pain. This is true if Display Zoom is set to Zoomed rather than standard Credit: @ Christopher Pickslay*

Comment: Why not just take a video of the screen?  Or use a library which does that for you:  https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder

Comment: I am unsure as why i disregarded that as i've done quiet a bit of research on existing libraries that allow you to record the screen, and ran into ASScreenRecorder, though chose to try the following.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked:

```
var limit = 80 

func capture() {

     if limit > 0 {

     delay(0.03) {

     self.screenshot()

     self.capture()

   } else {

convertToVideo()

}

 func screenshot()  {

        var imageSize = CGSize.zero

        let orientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
        if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) {
            imageSize = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size
        } else {
            imageSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height, height: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.width)
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 0)
        for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
            window.drawHierarchy(in: window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        images.append(image!)

        limit = limit - 1

    }
```

Delay is :

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
        deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)
}
```