# Is there an Objective-C equivalent to XNA's update function?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xna

What function can be used in Objective-C, for iPhone, that works like the `update` function in the XNA framework?

Like this:  [image] for automantic update.

Comment: Implement the `-(void) layoutSubviews` method of UIView ...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do the heavy lifting yourself, typically by using threading or an NSTimer object.

For example:

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.033f target:self
            selector:@selector(mainLoop:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

where the "selector" points to your game loop function. Make sure the game loop creates another NSTimer after calling Update and Render:

```
    - (void) mainLoop: (id) sender
    {
        [Update];
        [Render];

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:sleepPeriod target:self 
                selector:@selector(mainLoop:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
```

Also check out this thread for threading discussion: [What is a better way to create a game loop on the iPhone other than using NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96265/what-is-a-better-way-to-create-a-game-loop-on-the-iphone-other-than-using-nstimer)

Or Google "iOS gameloop NSTimer".