# Game Timers Slowing Down Overall Performance

Tags: iphone, performance, ios4, nstimer

I'm working on an iPhone App where I rely heavily on timers and animations, but I've realized my game is really **slowing down and lagging** on certain aspects of the game. I'm not quite sure how to improve this **without removing any animations or anything**.

Essentially what I'm using is the **accelerometer** to update my character's position (Left/Right). I also use **several timers** to read from different URLs, update images and the one that lags the most is one that loops an image to move from left to right.

Basically I'm using **about 6 or 7 timers and the Accelerometer**, is there a way I can improve the performance of my game without having to remove any of my animations or changing the interval of the timers?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Are you using multi-threading? and what intervals are your timers set for?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, I'm using multiple NSTimers and they run at the same time. The intervals vary from (0.1 to 15)seconds.

Comment: I strongly recommend ditching timers, and go with an actual game loop in a separate thread. See also this question, which has a solid example answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96265/what-is-a-better-way-to-create-a-game-loop-on-the-iphone-other-than-using-nstimer

Comment: Oh, and just to make sure you don't miss the link in the posted answer: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/ is a perfect introduction to game loops, regardless of language.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I'm not quite sure what the difference between these is. What is so different about using threads and using timers? Like does it speed up the game? and what if i want to change the intervals for each animation, how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using NSTimer to animate, you might want to look at using the animationImages property in UIImageView  (which lets you show multiple frames of animation, possibly looping) or beginAnimations within UIView (which lets you move an object along a path, among other things).

A good place to start is with this question on [recommend reading for iPhone animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907068/recommended-reading-for-iphone-core-animation), although for reference the documentation in XCode and Apple's programming guides are good sources by themselves.

What others have suggested - in terms of using a game loop - make sense, too, but depending on the complexity of your game, sometimes just letting the iOS SDK take care of your animations for you can be good enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have already thought of that, the only problem is that I don't have as much control when I use that. Besides most of my timers just perform several if statements and change a UIImage's image or change the location.

Comment: Do you have a ton of UIImageViews and the like? Sadly, iOS isn't too efficient at handling a large number of animating images. If so, you might need to switch to using OpenGL to handle animation. Plus having just one game loop (rather than multiple timers) might also reduce some of the iOS overhead.

Comment: or, like, wait 3 weeks and get an iPhone 5 :D

Comment: Yes, I have around 120 Images, and around 20 of those animate somehow which is really slowing down my game. If I use one game loop how can I change the interval? Because I have like an image that moves every 10th of a second but I also have a method that updates every 15 seconds

Comment: Something that's like "once every 15 seconds" -- sure, a timer could be used there. Your game loop itself could run at 10 fps, and you might want to use CADisplayLink to do that. Kinda sounds to me like you might need to make the jump to using OpenGL, or a library like Cocos2D, in order to get better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try use **Allocation**
RUN-> RUN WITH PERFORMANCE TOOLS->Allocation
to see which part is overload in the application